# Change the widget of just one field in django-crispy-forms with the layout object AppendedText

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/) to render the form of a model in [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). django-crispy-forms already integrates very well with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and has defined a layout object for the `AppendedText` widget:

[image: AppendedText widget]

I have the following model in my django `models.py`

```
class Historia(models.Model):
    persona         = models.ForeignKey('Persona', 
                                  blank=False, 
                                  null=True,
                                  related_name='historias')
    fecha           = models.DateTimeField(unique=True, 
                                auto_now_add=True)
    motivo          = models.TextField()
    peso            = models.DecimalField(blank=True,
                                   max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    talla           = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    tension         = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    pulso           = models.IntegerField()
    diagnostico     = models.TextField()
    tratamiento     = models.TextField()
    pendiente       = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

and I define the following `modelform` in `forms.py`:

```
class HistoriaForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Historia

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HistoriaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_id = 'nueva_historia_form'
        self.helper.form_action = 'nueva_historia'

        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.helper.error_text_inline = False

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('crear', 'Crear'))
```

My question is how can I change the widget of the `peso` field without having to create a new `widget` subclass since `django-crispy-forms` already defines a layout object. Please also note that I do not want to enumerate all other fields in order to do this like:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Legend',
                'nombre',
                'apellido',
                AppendedText('peso', 'kg')
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
```

since I will have to keep editing the helper layout if I decide to add new fields in my model from which standard widgets are already very useful.

**Edit:** I have also seen the methods to access the layouts in a helper like `self.helper.layout[0] = AppendedText('peso', 'kg')` but I do not know the index of the field I would like to change and it would be much nicer if I could just write `self.helper.layout['peso'] = AppendedText('peso', 'kg')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

django-crispy-forms does have an API for these kind of things:
http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html

You could simply do:

```
form.helper['peso'].wrap(AppendedText, "kg")
```

Comment: That works with a small change `form.helper['peso'].wrap(AppendedText, "peso", "kg")`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry Gustavo, but that you pointed out is a bug. You shouldn't have to pass the name of the field. As in other cases when you wrap several fields, there is no way to pass field names for all of them. This has been addressed in this commit https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/commit/c4bb6e6a6e15c984829f16494ac9fde399b2f9ca and will be part of crispy-forms 1.2.5

Comment: It still gives a `You need to set a layout in your FormHelper` error for me, but I don't want to because I can't be bothered referencing every single field in the layout. I'd also have to go and change it if I add more fields.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is what worked for me without having to be too verbose and keeping it simple. In the `__init__` method just do the following:

```
for i, field in enumerate(self.helper.layout):
    if field == 'peso':
        self.helper.layout[i] = AppendedText('peso', 'kg')
```

This works perfectly fine if the field you are looking for is in the first level of hierarchy in the `layout` object, otherwise you would have to be more specific about what you are looking. For example if your field is in a `DIV` container you would first will have to check whether `field.__class__ == DIV` and then introspect into the `DIV` field which is not as easy as it seems.

It would be nice, however, to have the API of the `layout` object to support filter queries